# XHTML editor wanted!

Tags: java, html, xhtml, editor, xhtmlrenderer

I need an editor that outputs clean HTML, and preferably strict XHTML with CSS, as I am going to display the resulting pages as help pages in a java application using [xhmtlrenderer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) ("Flying Saucer") which apparently very much prefers XHTML with CSS 2.1.

Having searched stackoverflow for [HTML editor](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+editor) and [XHTML editor](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xhtml+editor), I've found several mentioned. [Aptana](http://www.aptana.org/) is one, [Eclipse's Web Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/) is another, and [KompoZer](http://www.kompozer.net/) is a third.

I am going to try these out. With this question, I ask whether there are other good options that would satisfy my requirements, and if there are any one of these mentioned or new ones that you'd recommend in particular, that I should focus a bit extra on?

Comment: I would personally use Eclipse but that's because I write mostly code and already have it installed.  If you put proper DTD/XSD declarations in your XHTML then eclipse will enforce strict compliance.  I don't *think* it has a WYSIWYG editor though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two options in my opinion:

If you need to design your page layout visually, go to Dreamweaver. I don't like any Eclipse (X)HTML visual editor, they are buggy and the preview funcion is not even near the one offered by Dreamweaver.

If you have knowledge or are more concerned about the content of your xhtml file, then use the HTML Editor of Eclipse Web Tools and always place this strict XHTML DOCTYPE as your first document line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

And as said before, you can always check your code against HTML Tidy to validate this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++: http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm

The only Editor! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If on Mac OS X,

BBEdit, http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/

Komodo Edit, http://www.activestate.com/node/43

TextMate, http://macromates.com/

Can always run XHTML/HTML code through HTML Tidy http://tidy.sourceforge.net/